Trying to print base64 document fails with "parameter is not valid"
I am trying this:
try
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes))
    {
        // Load the PDF document
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(memoryStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly);

        // Print each page
        for (int i = 0; i < pdfDocument.PageCount; i++)
        {
            using (var printDocument = new PrintDocument())
            {
                printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;

                // Handle the PrintPage event
                printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            PdfSharp.Events.RenderEvents renderEvents = new PdfSharp.Events.RenderEvents();
                            XGraphics graphics = XGraphics.FromGraphics(e.Graphics, new XSize(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height), renderEvents);

                            // Get the current page to print
                            var page = pdfDocument.Pages[i];
                            var pageWidth = page.Width;
                            var pageHeight = page.Height;

                            // Calculate the scale to fit the page
                            var scaleX = e.MarginBounds.Width / pageWidth;
                            var scaleY = e.MarginBounds.Height / pageHeight;
                            var scale = Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY);

                            // Center the page on the printer
                            var xPos = e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - (pageWidth * scale)) / 2;
                            var yPos = e.MarginBounds.Top + (e.MarginBounds.Height - (pageHeight * scale)) / 2;

                            // Draw the content of the PDF page
                            XImage xImage = XImage.FromStream(memoryStream);
                            graphics.DrawImage(xImage, xPos, yPos, pageWidth * scale, pageHeight * scale);

                            // Draw rectangle for the page border
                            graphics.DrawRectangle(XPens.Black, xPos, yPos, pageWidth * scale, pageHeight * scale);
                };

                // Trigger the print job
                printDocument.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}

But when the actual printing is triggered, it fails with an error

Parameter is not valid

Now I assume this comes from the render events that I left empty, but I couldn't really find anything I would want to put in this; but maybe this isn't the issue at all.
Anybody might have any tips?
Thank you!

Where does the error occur? That a typical GDI+ error that should rather happen when you work against the Graphics object shown in your code and has less likely somethign todo with the printing part of it.

You are going to need a library that can render PDF to a GDI image, such as Ghostscript.net

I don't know where the error "Parameter is not valid" comes from.
But the line graphics.DrawImage(xImage, [...] will never do what you expect, because the graphics object was created for a GDI+ Graphics object while the xImage object was created for a PDF file.
GDI+ cannot draw PDF images.
XGraphics objects created for PDF pages can draw PDF pages.
But long story short: PDFsharp cannot print PDF files and cannot render PDF files.

thank you,your right.
